# Is there a way to distinguish between buttons pressed Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am creating a Flask app in python and I have come across an issue.

I was simply wondering if say you have two buttons on index.html and they do separate things

Say you have a html file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Site!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form action="#" method="post">

    <button type="submit">Somthing1</button>
    <button type="submit">Somthing2</button>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a function like this

```
@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        # Solution here
    return "Hello, World!"
```

How can I tell whether button labeled "Somthing1" was pressed or "Something2"?

Comment: Since my answer helped you, please accept it so others can see that your issue is resolved and find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to give your buttons a name.

```html
<button type="submit" name="1">Somthing1</button>
<button type="submit" name="2">Somthing2</button>
```

Then, in your Python code, you can have code like this:

```py
if(request.method == "POST"):
     one = request.form.get("1")
     two = request.form.get("2")
     if one is not None:
         # Do stuff for Somthing1
     elif two is not None:
         # Do stuff for Somthing2
```

`request.form.get` returns the element if it exists, and returns `None` otherwise.